# Get data from GridFS using mongoengine

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine, gridfs

dear colleagues.
In my project I have successfully saved data(image) in mongodb using mongoengine. I have problem with getting image from mongodb and displaying it on the client. I'm not using local storage, so this is causing the problem with loading the page (the page will not be shown until  **photo_view**  function has been loaded the file and stored to temp file.

This is a short cut of my saved object in mongodb

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53c123edcb596046fdf6c746"),
    "main_photo" : ObjectId("53c123e1cb596046fdf6c6fc"),
    "create_date" : ISODate("2014-07-12T12:02:41.036Z")
}
```

The actual file is saved in  **db.fs.files**  using GridFS.
This is the models.py file

```
class Photo(Document):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.create_date
    main_photo = FileField()
    create_date = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

The problem is in **photo_view** function

```
@login_required
def photo_view(request, id, template_name):
    params = {}
    obj = Photo.objects.get(id = id)
    print obj.main_photo.read()
    params['object'] = obj
    return render(request, template_name, params)
```

The  **obj.main_photo.read()**  is an actual file. How can I achieve in loading page without storing data in temporary file on my server. Even if I will load the data, the function  **photo_view**  will not finish until it is loaded/copied from  **GridFS** .

Comment: Hi, could you clarify, what's your problem? Are you trying to give out the data from gridfs on your server to the client? So, what's the problem, you just read the data from gridfs file into your `str` buffer and that's it. No temporary file is needed. Just say `Photo.objects.get(id=id).main_photo.get().read()`.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. The problem is if I read it in my views.py then I have to wait until the image will be loaded. There is another problem: it is not very good to send files with params. If I would use local storage then I can access to them via /media/ url in my html template, but what should I do if I use gridFS?

Comment: I think it's ok to read the file into a string on your server side, cause GridFS tries to use RAM instead of Hard Drive to store its files (see these tests for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12894542/mongodb-gridfs-file-sizes-huge-for-relatively-small-file). So the file read in your script in fact goes from RAM to RAM, which should be fast. Then you can pass the string with file contents to the template in context params.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I think if I had a single file or image then it would be ok to send it, but problem might arrive when I try to open a page with lots of images.

Comment: I guess, in any case you'll have a cache ahead of your server for serving static content that will serve your images and/or often visited pages. So it might not be performance-critical, though I don't know for sure. I don't have an idea of how to do it better. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much. My current solution is just like you said. I think I will live it for some time. Thank you